# How to share an array between two applications in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, service, sharing

I've got an application `appA` and another application `appB`, `appA` is for front end and `appB` is for admin end.

I've got an array `queries` that I keep building using a service through a controller in `appA` and I need that array list in the `appB`. But I get an empty array when I try to retrieve the array list in a controller in `appB`.

When `appB` is loaded, the page is refreshed.

Following is the service I use to store and share the array:

```
.factory('myService', function() {
    var queries = [];
    var factory = {};

    factory.addQuery = function(query) {
        queries.push(query);
        return queries;
    };
    factory.allQueries = function() {
        return queries;
    };
    return factory;
});
```

**Application A**

```
angular.module("appA", ['ui.router', ..)
```

**Application B**

```
angular.module("appB", ['ui.router', ..)
```

Could somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be to use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

To set it:

```
localStorage.setItem('queries', queriesVariable);
```

to get it from another app:

```
localStorage.getItem('queries');
```

or just:

```
localStorage.queries;
```

And if you don't need the data to persist after a refresh, you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).

Comment: just a small note that the localstorage will work only for apps on the same domain.

Comment: @MajoB Yes, thank you. I assumed that since OP said one app is for the front end and the other for the back end, and they are usually on the same domain.

Comment: @MajoB, @Shomz: I got an `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorageProvider <- $localStorage` when I tried `localStorage.setItem('queries', queries);` in `appA` and `localStorage.getItem('queries');` `appB`. What am I missing? Am I supposed to add a module to the angular applications to get it to work?

Comment: It's not a dependency, it's a plain JS feature. Should work pretty much out of the box. Just make sure you stringify the array.

Comment: @Shomz: Even when I do the following I am getting only the last element added to the `queries` array `queries.push(query);
localStorage.setItem('queries', JSON.stringify(queries));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queries')));`.

Comment: Not sure I understand... `queries.push(query)` will add `query` to the end of the `queries` array. Then the two localStorage command will set/get the current state of the `queries` array. What's the problem?